# Use gatsby-image's tracedSVG as the actual picture

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-remark-image

**TL;DR: Is it possible to use Gatsby's rendered tracedSVG from childImageSharp as the actual picture on your website?**

Long version:

So, I was working on a small website for my recital with *Gatsby* earlier today and while I was hosting it on my machine the pictures load just fine, but when I deployed the project to *Github Pages*, the image files failed to load, only the *tracedSVG* placeholders loaded.

Now I am sure there is a solution for this; I haven't yet looked into that. **The thing is**, I kinda like how those artsy *tracedSVGs* look on my website, and I want to keep them. I can of course, just leave it as is, but if there is a proper and more elegant way of doing this, I'd love to know.

[image]

I tried

```
fluid 
{            
    tracedSVG  
}
```

instead of

```
fluid
{
   ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
}
```

in the js file and the images and the placeholders failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Gatsby's rendered tracedSVG from childImageSharp
> as the actual picture on your website?

Short answer: yes, you can. Your query should look like this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "/path/to/your/traced/svg/traced.svg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(width: 125, height: 125) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG        
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Then, use your `gatsby-image`:

```
export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: How do you get the location of the generated SVG placeholders? I see you are using relativePath there, but I don't know the path to those generated placeholder images.